# How can I speed up receiving my XMR

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

First-time poster. Thanks for reading.

I've setup the GUI client and transferred some XMR. The client is "waiting for the daemon to sync" and I've read the posts about this being necessary. Thing is, I'm 4 days into sync now (on SSD) and unable to access my XMR as a result - I've verified that I own the amount using my view key, so all good there.

Question is: Is there a way that I can get access to my coins now without needing to wait for the whole blockchain to sync. At the current rate, it looks like it'll be another 4 -5 days

Comment: Can you go to the `Settings` page -> `Log` tab, type `status`, and post the output here?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that when you first set up the wallet you chose **Simple Mode (bootstrap)** or **Advanced Mode**, both of which require downloading the blockchain to your computer. If so, there is a **Simple Mode** (without bootstrap) that instead of downloading the blockchain, connects to a remote node, allowing you access to your funds almost instantaneously. It should be noted that this may compromise some aspects of your privacy. The remote node will have access to your IP address for example (unless you're using a VPN or ToR).

To check your wallet mode, go to `Settings` > `Info` and see `Wallet mode`:

[image: Wallet Mode indicator]

If you are not in **Simple Mode**, and are happy to accept the trade-offs that come with using a remote node, you can switch your wallet mode.

If your wallet is open, you need to close it first. Go to `Settings` > `Wallet` > `Close this wallet`:

[image: Close wallet]

The main menu (Welcome to Monero screen) will open. At the bottom left, click on Change wallet mode button, and on the next page select **Simple Mode**. Next, open your wallet file again.

[image: Choosing Simple Mode]

The wallet should automatically connect to a remote mode and show your balance, but in the event it doesn't there's info on how to find a remote public node in the guide on getmonero.org: https://www.getmonero.org/tr/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html